# PHP POST not working. Sending but NULL params?

Tags: php, json, curl

I have an issue when trying to send JSON to a Java Web Service. I am using cURL to post JSON  however the web service responds that the paramters I send are NULL see error message below.

```
$data = "{'firstname': 'tom', 'surname' : 'tom', 'companyName' : 'test','phone' : 01234567, 'email' : 'test@test.com'}";                                                                                                              
$ch = curl_init('http://10.50.1.71:8080/SME/api/details.json');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($buildApplicationJSON))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

and the response I get is -

> string(1042)
>   "{"errors":[{"object":"com.application.AppDetails","field":"firstname","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property
>   [firstname] of class [class com.application.AppDetails] cannot be
>   null"},{"object":"com.application.AppDetails","field":"surname","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property
>   [surname] of class [class com.application.AppDetails] cannot be
>   null"},{"object":"com.application.AppDetails","field":"companyName","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property
>   [companyName] of class [class com.application.AppDetails] cannot be
>   null"},{"object":"com.application.AppDetails","field":"phone","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property
>   [phone] of class [class com.application.AppDetails] cannot be
>   null"},{"object":"com.application.AppDetails","field":"email","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property
>   [email] of class [class com.application.AppDetails] cannot be
>   null"},{"object":"com.application.AppDetails","field":"sourceCode","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property
>   [sourceCode] of class [class com.application.AppDetails] cannot be
>   null"}]}"

UPDATE: Still not working. The $data JSON line was not an issue. In my previous version I had an array and used json_encode

```
$buildApplication = array(
    'firsname'          => 'Keith',
    'surname'           => 'Francis',
'companyName'       => 'Keiths Mobile Discos',
    'phone'             => '07123456789',
    'email'             => 'keith.francis@freedom-finance.co.uk',
    'sourceCode'        => 'W00T'
);
$data = json_encode($buildApplication);                                                                                                             
$ch = curl_init('http://10.50.1.71:8080/SME/api/details.json');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($buildApplicationJSON))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: what is `$buildApplicationJSON` in the context of `$data` ?

Comment: change `$data = '{"firstname": "tom", "surname" : "tom", "companyName" : "test","phone" : 01234567, "email" : "test@test.com"}';`

Comment: Use array $data['firstname'] = "value"; ....

Comment: @A-2-A Isn't that still invalid? The keys shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Native json the keys should indeed be quoted, most applications don't require this though. However, AWS is one such example that requires both keys and values be quoted.

Comment: Check updated edit. Still not working

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is incorrect. See the result of this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf3x5yrc/).

Now you could rewrite this string to be proper JSON, but that is quite error-prone. 
Instead, let `json_encode` do the work for you.

Define `$data` as a PHP array:

```
$data = ['firstname' => 'tom', 'surname' => 'tom', 'companyName' => 'test', 'phone' => 01234567, 'email' => 'test@test.com'];
```

Then use `json_encode` when you want to pass it to curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

Better yet, try to encode it before hand and check that it was successfuly encoded.

```
if( $jsondata = json_encode($data) ){
    //$jsondata is valid json
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I already tried an array to json_encode (see my edited text) and I get the same result. Cannot understand why I am getting null response..

Comment: In your update, you are json_encoding the data twice. Only json_encode the PHP array once

Answer (score 0):

The string you send is *not* valid JSON. That is why the receiving side fails to extract values from it.

Note that there is a difference between:

```
{'firstname': 'tom', 'surname' : 'tom', 'companyName' : 'test','phone' : 01234567, 'email' : 'test@test.com'}
```

and

```
{"firstname": "tom", "surname": "tom", "companyName": "test", "phone": 342391, "email": "test@test.com"}
```

It usually is safest if you use phps json encoding function instead of trying to hard code things:

```
<?php
$data = json_encode([
    'firstname' => 'tom',
    'surname' => 'tom',
    'companyName' => 'test',
    'phone' => 01234567,
    'email' => 'test@test.com'
]);
```

Comment: Up voting to bring to 0 because I see nothing wrong with this.